# Neo4j new cypher format of relationship pattern

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The relationship pattern in queries is changing, but the documentation is lacking. I get a "pending depreciation" message when writing this query:

```
match path = (p:Person)-[r:father|mother*0..5]->(a:Person) 
return path limit 25
```

How do I write this to confirm to the new requirements?

It needs to be something like this but with some portion of the father|mother*0..5 moved into the relationships(path)

```
 match path = (p:Person)-[r:father|mother*0..5]->(a:Person) 
 with *, relationships(path) as r
 return path limit 25
```

That query runs okay but the error message persists.

What is the proper new format?

Answer (score 2):

I assume Neo4j is complaining about the  `r` . Can you try this:

```
 match path = (p:Person)-[:father|mother*0..5]->(a:Person) 
 with *, relationships(path) as r
 return path limit 25
```

The more complex case i would suggest to split the match

```
   match path1= (p:Person{RN:5242})-[:father|mother*0..15]->(mrca:Person),
       path2= (mrca)<-[:father|mother*0..15]-(b:Person{RN:1}) return length(path1), length(path2)
```

Comment: Yes, it was complaining about the r.  Your suggestion works. Thanks!

Comment: It's more complicated. In trying to find genealogy relationships, you can count the hops to a common ancestor. So here is the query:

match path = (p:Person{RN:5242})-[r1:father|mother*0..15]->(mrca:Person)<-[r2:father|mother*0..15]-(b:Person{RN:1})  return size(r1),size(r2)

It gives the error. So how would you use the with*, relationships(path) as r to capture the hop of r1 and r2

Comment: I extended the answer

Comment: I agree that splitting the query in the more complex case is reasonable. To compute the relationship you need the lengths of the two paths and also the number of common ancestors. Your half cousin shared only one grandparent and a full cousin shares 2. 

Why is the current cypher strategy being depreciated? Does will not be supported mean it is going away? 

This query work well.

match path = (p:Person{RN:5424})-[r1:father|mother*0..15]->(mrca:Person)<-[r2:father|mother*0..15]-(b:Person{RN:1}) return count(*) as Ct_MRCAs,size(r1) as Path1,size(r2) as Path2

Thanks again for your help!